# How to group and sum timesheet rows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a timesheet model that looks like:

```
timesheet
-id
-total_hours
-user_id
-date
```

Now I want to produce a report that looks like:

```
user_id   total_hours
```

(I will have a where clause that will select the rows for a given date range, but that part I understand).

Is this a query I can use activerecord for or should I just use psql for this and use raw sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` with `Group` like below:

```
TimeSheet.select("user_id,SUM(total_hours) as total_hours").group(:user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following:

`TimeSheet.group(:user_id).sum(:total_hours)`

Answer (score 0):

If required result in the hash format like

```
{251=>0, 129=>2, 195=>4}
```

here 251 and 129 is user_id and 0 and 2 is total_hours

Try this:

```
TimeSheet.group(:user_id).sum(:total_hours)
```

Otherwise(For ActiveRecord::Relation):

```
TimeSheet.select("user_id,SUM(total_hours) as total_hours").group(:user_id)
```